# mysql delete and then insert. Does not insert into delete line for AI table! Why?

Tags: mysql

I am not sure I am correct in this. 
I have insert 5 rows with values with id as primary key and autoincrement.
Then I delete row number 2-4. 
when I insert on a new line with none id, the new id becomes "6". Is this normal? 
How is it possible if you want the mysql to insert in the deleted row? what are the settings?

Comment: And work with it, don't try to change it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is normal. If you want to insert with a specific ID number you have to specify that number on your insert statement.

The idea of auto **increment** is for the value to continually increase.

Comment: +1, yes, and as 'id' is an _identifier_, it would be thoroughly confusing if the actual entity it identified changes through time (instead of it's properties, which may of course change).

Answer (score 0):

This is normal, though for some database engines you might receive 2, but usually it will be 6.  In MSSQL it is possible to specify a value for an autoinc field with particular setting. Not sure what it is in mysql.

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected behavior. Autoincrement primary keys are designed to be unique and continually increasing - so they are not assigned again.

If you `TRUNCATE` a table the autoincrement value is being reset while it stays as it is if you delete all rows with an `DELETE` query - that's a subtle but sometimes important difference.

As webdestroya suggested, the only possibility to reuse old and deleted autoincrement values is to set them specifically on the `INSERT` statement.